# Solving the homogeneous system associated with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

So i have this matrix

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 3 & -6 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and I want to solve the homogeneous system associated with it

I re-write the matrix as

$$                       
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 3 & -6 \\      
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}  · (x,y,z)= $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$

However, I do not know how to proceed from here as I've started studying   matrices as a solo student from a couple of days.

The solutions are  the linear combinations of (1,1,1) and (-1,1,0).

I am confused on how to get to these solutions which are the linear combinations of (1,1,1) and (-1,1,0) and if anybody could show me the steps the simplest way possible it would be great ! Thanks!

Comment: Matrices have no "solutions": they are just matrices, so what do you really mean?

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to solving the homogeneous system associated with the matrix which gives me the linear combinations of (1,0,0) and (-1,1,0)

Comment: The r.h.s. of your system should be a column vector.

Comment: Yes, they are, i just couldn't write them in the right for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The homogeneous system of linear equations whose coefficients matrix is your matrix is equivalent with the homogeneous system whose coefficients matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\0&0&0\\
1&1&-2\end{pmatrix}\implies x+y-2z=0\implies \text{Span}\,\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

Observe that both vectors you mention at the end of your question belong to the solution space (the span) above, and they both are linearly independents, so you can choose those two as basis or else you can take the basis I wrote above.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand the last Part. I understood where you get x+y-2z=0 and that is really great. However, i am a little confused from here. With this equation x+y−2z=0, how do i proceed to get the exact results (1,1,1) and (-1,0,0)?

Comment: My confusion arises since I've been studying vectors only from a couple of days and i don't really grasp what you wrote above, i'm sorry

Comment: @BM97 I really don't know then how to explain this to you. Perhaps someone else...This kind of exercises, as far as I know, is given when one has already studied the basics of linear (or vector) spaces, linear combinations, dependency and etc., and certainly not after just two days...

Comment: Okay , i got that the span is equal to (1,-1,0), (2,0,1).... would that be okay as an answer?? Its as fair as the vectors (1,1,1) and (-1,1,0) correct?

Comment: Meaning that if i write (1,1,1)(-1,1,0) or (1,-1,0)(2,0,1) its the same thing correct?

Comment: Well, the span of those two vectors is the set (which in fact is a subspace) of all their linear combinations, which is a pretty infinite set. This span equals the span of $\;(1,1,1)\,,\,\,(1,-1,0)\;$ , as both two-elements sets span the same subspace of dimension two.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple: your system is equivalent to the single equation
$$x+y-2z=0\iff z=\tfrac12(x+y)$$
so the subspace $S$ of solutions is isomorphic to $K^2$ ($K$ is the base field) via the isomorphism:
\begin{align}
K^2&\longrightarrow S\subset K^3\\
(x,y)&\longmapsto (x,y,\tfrac12(x+y))
\end{align}
Now an isomorphism maps a basis onto a basis, so determine a basis of $K^2$ that maps onto the indicated basis.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand the last Part. I understood where you get x+y-2z=0 and that is really great. However, i am a little confused from here. With this equation x+y−2z=0, how do i proceed to get the exact results (1,1,1) and (-1,0,0)?

Comment: Which values of $(x,y)$ map to $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,10)$? Is the  set of these values a basis of $K^2$?